Is it bad practice to use empty classes as containers for methods?
I have a few functions that do basically the same task but using different algorithms. Since these algorithms are all related (they belong to the same parent process) I've organized them in my package my_package as methods of an empty class in a module file called my_empty_class.py as so:
class my_empty_class:
    """Define an empty class to hold the methods"""

    def func1(param1, param2, param3):
        # algo 1
        return results

    def func2(param1, param3):
        # algo 2
        return results

    def func3(param2, param4):
        # algo 3
        return results

The package files are organized as:
my_package/
    __init__.py
    my_empty_class.py
    another_module.py
    onemore_module.py
    ...

This is what my __init__.py looks like:
from .my_empty_class import my_empty_class as my_empty_class
from .another_module import another_module as another_module
from .onemore_module import onemore_module as onemore_module
...

Finally, I call the methods with:
import my_package

res1 = my_package.my_empty_class.func1(param1, param2, param3)
res2 = my_package.my_empty_class.func2(param1, param3)
res3 = my_package.my_empty_class.func3(param2, param4)

Is this bad practice? Because it works, but it feels like it is. Is there maybe a better/more recommended way to go about this?

But why do you need the class at all? If you removed the class you could get less typing to call your functions.

Use modules to organize free functions.

@quamrana I explained it, all functions belong to the same parent process. They are organized in a single class because of that

decorate them as @staticmethods so have a "fixed" type (function)

From the code you show, you could just delete the class and type less. Belonging to the same "parent process" has no bearing.

if empty class works for you then use it.

It's weird, cumbersome, and unnecessary.

@JohnGordon how would you organize the package? Considering of course there are more modules and classes than this one

Gabriel Its important to do what @cards is telling you.  right now you would be misusing the signature for a class method (regular methods get a self object, class methods get a cls object and static methods get no extra object.  You would want to use the decorators for the class and static methods to identify them as such.   also by convention the first character of a class is uppercased to indicate its a class name.

Downvoting this because you disagree with the pattern is wrong in my opinion. The question itself is fine, especially in it's "what's a better way to do this?" interpretation.
This is a useful thing for people to find, especially newcomers. We need to stop downvoting and duplicate closing everything into oblivion, it's a bad look for the site.

It's just unnecessary and you can achieve the same with less code.
Instead of:

class my_empty_class:
    """Define an empty class to hold the methods"""

    def func1(param1, param2, param3):
        # algo 1
        return results

    def func2(param1, param3):
        # algo 2
        return results

    def func3(param2, param4):
        # algo 3
        return results


write:
"""A module to hold the functions"""

def func1(param1, param2, param3):
    # algo 1
    return results

def func2(param1, param3):
    # algo 2
    return results

def func3(param2, param4):
    # algo 3
    return results

Instead of:

from .my_empty_class import my_empty_class as my_empty_class


write:
from . import my_empty_class

(as my_empty_class was already unnecessary before.)
Of course, the name my_empty_class now does not fit anymore, because there is no empty class, and you should find a better name, like algorithms.

One point that's not addressed by this answer: If you want to have multiple separate groups of loose methods (which I assume is the whole reason for the question), then use separate files. That's what they are for. Using classes for this is just counter intuitive. If it's not worth separating into files, is it really worth giving it separate namespaces?

Noting horribly wrong with doing this as a class but its important to do what @cards is telling you in the comments.
You would be misusing the signature for a class method (regular methods get a self object, class methods get a cls object and static methods get no extra object. You would want to use the decorators for the class and static methods to identify them as such.
Also by convention the first character of a class is uppercased to indicate its a class name.
